# GBQ window function AND arithmetic operations

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

Does anyone know if it is possible to do any arithmetic operation on a result derived using GBQ window functions?

For example, can I increase row_number by 100 (some number) using pseudocode like this:

```
SELECT 100 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY x_id DESC) increased_row_num
FROM Table1
...
```

Comment: vkp thank you for quick response. But when I execute this query I got Error: Missing function in Analytic Expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use subquery for that

```
SELECT 100 + row_num AS increased_row_num FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY x_id DESC) AS row_num
FROM Table1
)
```

Comment: Thank you Mosha Pasumansky this is definitely one solution, but I'we hoped that there is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

> but I'we hoped that there is another solution

With BigQuery Standard SQL expected functionality works now as is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 100 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY x_id DESC) increased_row_num
FROM Table1
```

See [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#bigquery-enable-sql-web) and [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)